# ADAL - Access Token getting expired after 1 hour and not getting refresh token

Tags: wcf, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, access-token, refresh-token

I have create a WFC application to push the Data into Dynamics CRM.
For Authentication with Dynamics CRM i am using Application User (S2S authentication)and In WFC i am getting access token using below code:

```
 string ClientId = "********-542e-440b-b718-69f7826ae60a"; // App Id
 string ClientSecret = "*******Ovm4/00jU?tYT.tw5t6a5@@8n";
 string resource = "https://*****.crm8.dynamics.com";
 ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);
 var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientcred);
```

Every thing is working fine till 1 hour after that i am getting 401(Unauthorized) error because access token getting expired after 1 hour.

Now My question is :-

Can i increase the access token life more than 1 hour, which is coming as 1 hour by default is 1 hour?

Using above mentioned code why i am only getting access token but not getting refresh token? (which we can use to refresh my access token).
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get a refresh token because ADAL handles them internally.
And you don't need one anyway in this case.

You can get a new token by calling `AcquireToken` again:

```
var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientcred);
```

Actually, you can call AcquireToken before every HTTP call.
ADAL will give you a token from its memory cache if it is still valid, and get a new one if it does not have one.

Though since you are using client credentials flow, there is actually no refresh token returned ever.
Because a client app like this does not need it.
You have all the credentials to get new tokens with them anyway, a refresh token would only needlessly complicate the flow here.